# Is the Fizzco DSRC followed by the Charge Beam and Rivet Blaster, the three priciest weapons?

Tags: sunset-overdrive

I'm saving my OverCharge up to buy weapons from priciest to cheapest, so I need to know if the Fizzco DSRC is the costliest at 200,000 with the Charge Beam and Rivet Blaster as the distant seconds at 100,000.

But no one's compiled a list of all of the weapon prices, so just wanting to clarify what's the most expensive thing I have to buy, which would make things a lot easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it.

From priciest to cheapest, the list seems to be:

1. Fizzco DSRC: 200,000
2. Charge Beam / Rivet Blaster: 100,000
3. The Shocker: 70,000
4. ProPain Launcher: 65,000
5. Plague Bomb: 60,000
6. Hair Spray Bomb: 55,000
7. Multi-Lock Rocket Launcher: 50,000
8. Fizzbot Rifle: 40,000
9. Rager: 35,000
10. Hotty Shotty: 30,000
11. Turret Copter: 25,000
12. Shield Buddy / Shorty Shotty / Proximity Mine: 20,000
13. Head-Banger Gun: 16,000
14. The Roman Candle: 15,000
15. Nothin' But The Hits: 12,000
16. One-Handed Dragon / Taunt Bot: 10,000
17. The Dude: 9,500
18. Captain Ahab: 9,000
19. AK-FOFF: 8,000
20. Acid Sprinkler: 7,500
21. Freeze Bomb: 5,500